# is there a way to get page views count by page category

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I would like to know my requirement is common for every one or not? I am trying to show the page views count by category in my blog, to do this I am using google reporting analytics API. I have setup everything and able to get the page views count by specific given dates like below.

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("today");
$dateRange->setEndDate("today");

$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
```

Here I am getting only page views count, but I am not able to get the views count by category.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution: 
Using

```
Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest object.
```

Which provides all reporting related data.

```
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($profileId);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
$path = "ga:pagePath==" . $page;
```

ga:pagePath is to complete page url results :
Ex : www.websitename.com/category/page.html

For the above url, If we want to get the information by category, we can use

```
$path = ga:pagePathLevel1==" .$path
```

Followed below reference:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking

It helped me a lot, may help others..